# Third party path MX Maps

Tags: config-overrides, mx-google-map, themes

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious but cannot get MX Maps to work with custom third party theme folders.

The module appears fine when using the config_override for: 'third_party_path' for modules but when I override 'theme_folder_path' + 'theme_folder_url' to custom folders - I get a JS error on front end.

**mysite.com/themes/third_party/mx_google_map/mxgooglemap.js'**

All other modules + extensions work fine with the override :(

EE:2.8.1

MX Map: 1.5.3.140526

Comment: is error exactly as you show it? Where exactly this error? In CP or in frontend? Because in module I use *mxgooglemap.min.js* (not mxgooglemap.js) for CP. But if it is front end - this url is going from your template, not from module settings.

Comment: Ya see, I mentioned I was missing something. Reply as an answer and will mark accordingly :) Thx!

Comment: Hmm, that being said. When I edit config to point to a separate and custom theme folder (NOT /themes) it errors in the CP. Appears it doesnt recognise path_third_themes or url_third_themes.

Comment: hm... it is weird because I use ee()->config->item('theme_folder_url') for urls, so it is must be overwrite. Is this error on publish page? Could you please check next line in your files? It is the same? *https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-google-map-v1/blob/master/system/expressionengine/third_party/mx_google_map/ft.mx_google_map.php#L130-132* and as I mention before - in my files is no links to *mxgooglemap.js*, only to *mxgooglemap.min.js*. The link is entered on Publish page for channel which use MXGM for fieldtype.